# zigbee IAS Zone enroll callback function registration

Tags: zigbee

I know that normally this should check with the SDK manual. 
However, the zigbee module supplier mentions that the IAS cluster is out of scope of their SDK.

The callback function, for example, ZCL Report, could be registered in the allocation of the cluster.

My question is how to register my "enrollReq" callback function? where should I do it? I tried to register it in the creation of my cluster but this does not work.

Comment: Which MCU/SDK are you using?

Comment: The SDK I have in hand is Exegin zigbee SDK.

Comment: @AlessandroDaRugna, I check ember and TI's ( fire alaram system ) code but those dont point out where they register the callback. please let me know if you have any idea.

Comment: I don't know Ember / Exegin. I checked on some TI materials I have but no answer.